# How to disable disfluency removal for Google Cloud Speech to Text API

Tags: speech-to-text, google-speech-api

I am building an app that captures user audio and analyzes disfluency in a reader's speech, so it it important for me to know all forms of disfluency.

I noticed that Google's speech to text cloud API automatically removes disfluencies in speech. For example:

"so uhh, I will probably do that umm probably next week"

Gets transcribed to:

"so I will probably do that probably next week"

Is there a way to keep the uhhs and umms?

Comment: Hello. Did you find any solution?

Comment: @LouisBelmont I reached out to Google for help but unfortunately it seemed that disfluency removal was part of their trained model..

Comment: I also did not find anything like that for Google Speech. The closest I found was for IBM Watson, which has a hesitation and disfluencies marker that appears when disabling the smart formatting option but I have not yet been able to test

Comment: This process here could be useful https://www.isca-speech.org/archive/Interspeech_2019/pdfs/2836.pdf . They use Google Cloud API to get a transcript. They then use IBM Watson coupled with Gentle forced aligner to get disfluencies which are then combined with the Google transcript.